# rabbitmq access to vhost denied

Tags: rabbitmq, openstack, rabbitmqctl

I set up a controller host with rabbitmq-server running. From the nova host, I see that the nova-conductor cannot be reached. I checked on the controller host and I see the following in the logs :

```
  access to vhost 'None' refused for user 'openstack'
```

I have the following configuration settings for rabbitmq on the controller host:

```
    rabbitmqctl list_users
    Listing users ...
    guest   [administrator]
    openstack       []
```

When I list permissions I see openstack can access all resources

```
    list_permissions
    Listing permissions in vhost "/" ...
    guest   .*      .*      .*
    openstack       .*      .*      .*
```

I am able to authenticate with the rabbitmq-server - just unable to access the / vhost. For debugging, I would like to set up so that any client can access any resource (turn off access control altogether). Is that possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a relatively new change in either Kombu or [oslo.messages](https://github.com/openstack/oslo.messaging/). Previously if a virtual_host was not provided, it would default to `/`. This is no longer the case.

For it to work your `transport_url` needs to at the very least have one `/` at the end.

> transport_url = rabbit://stackrabbit:secretrabbit@127.0.0.1:5672/

You can take a look at for example devstack [here](https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/blob/master/lib/rpc_backend#L136) as a reference.

The actual upstream fix for the issue is available [here](https://github.com/openstack/oslo.messaging/commit/92b4080654b9ecb68250905e45eec65f41e5b161).

Comment: btw I fixed this recently for the Magnum gate https://review.openstack.org/#/c/610740/

Comment: Thanks. I specified transport_url = rabbit://stackrabbit:secretrabbit@127.0.0.1:5672// and now it works. I trashed my install and moved up to queens as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
access to vhost 'None' refused for user 'openstack'
```

Something is trying to access a vhost named `None`, which doesn't exist. The default vhost is named `/`. Since `None` is a keyword in Python I suspect there is an application bug or mis-configuration somewhere.

It's not possible to disable access control so I suggest creating a well-known user and password to use.

Comment: Is it possible to do a low level trace of the messaging? really stuck with this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can also send http requests to the vhost to get/set user permissions. You have to specify the host name as part of the url, but since the default vhost is '/' you have to substitute it for *'%2F'* i.e. *http://<ip>:<port>/api/vhosts/%2F/permissions*

e.g.

```
 curl -i -u guest:guest -h "content-type:application/json" -GET http://localhost:15672/api/permissions/%2F/guest
```

You can find a full list of api options by going to *http://<ip>:<port>/api/index.html*

Answer (score 1):

You have to substitute the `/` in the url with its url encoded version `%2F`.
The final url will look like: `127.0.0.1:5672/%2F`.

Comment: I had the same issue with dynamic shovel, thanks this worked for me